# tikz connection between drawings overlay or scope

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I am new in tikz, my problem is below on the picture, and the code, the question is how to connect drawings:

Here is my code, but the arrows are still missing, I can not find to put inside.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[align=center]
\coordinate (a) at (-1,-1);
\coordinate (b) at (1,-1);
\coordinate (c) at (1,1);
\coordinate (d) at (1,2);
\coordinate (e) at (-1,2);
\coordinate (f) at (-1,1);
\draw  (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- (d) -- (e) -- (f) -- cycle;
\draw  (c) -- (f);
\draw (a) node[blue,below left]{{1}};
\draw (b) node[blue,below right]{{2}};
\draw (c) node[blue,below right]{{4}};
\draw (f) node[blue,below left]{{3}};
\draw (c) node[red,above right]{{2}};
\draw (d) node[red,above right]{{4}};
\draw (e) node[red,above left]{{3}};
\draw (f) node[red,above left]{{1}};
\begin{scope}[xshift=100,yshift=-50]
\coordinate (a) at (-1,-1);
\coordinate (b) at (1,-1);
\coordinate (c) at (1,1);
\coordinate (f) at (-1,1);
\draw (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- (f) -- cycle;
\draw (a) node[blue,below left]{{1}};
\draw (b) node[blue,below right]{{2}};
\draw (c) node[blue,above right]{{4}};
\draw (f) node[blue,above left]{{3}};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=100,yshift=50]
\coordinate (c) at (1,1);
\coordinate (d) at (1,2);
\coordinate (e) at (-1,2);
\coordinate (f) at (-1,1);
\draw (c) -- (d) -- (e) -- (f) -- cycle; 
\draw (c) node[red,below right]{{2}};
\draw (d) node[red,above right]{{4}};
\draw (e) node[red,above left]{{3}};
\draw (f) node[red,below left]{{1}};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The code you show results in black circles at the corners of each rectangle while the included image does not show these rectangles. Could you please comment on that?

Comment: Hi and welcome. On your freehand drawn figure, the numbers go from 1 to 4. In your code, they go from 1 to 6. What does this drawing represent? What about these numbers?

Comment: @leandriis the black circles are only extras in the code

Comment: @AndréC this example for presentation of finite element method. The numbers is not necessary now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following might get you started:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning,arrows.meta,arrows}

\tikzset{
mymat/.style={
  matrix of math nodes,
  minimum width=1cm,
  minimum height=1.5cm,
  align=center,
  row sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
  nodes in empty cells
  },
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\matrix[mymat,anchor=west,style={nodes=draw}]
at (0,0) 
(mat1)
{
\\
\\
};
\matrix[mymat, above right =of mat1,anchor=north,style={nodes={draw}}]
(mat2)
{
\\
};
\matrix[mymat,below right=of mat1,anchor=south,style={nodes={draw}}]
(mat3)
{
\\
};
\path[->](mat1-1-1.center) edge[bend left=10] node [left] {} (mat2-1-1.west);
\path[->](mat1-2-1.center) edge[bend left=-10] node [left] {} (mat3-1-1.west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, please help me how can change the dimensions of rectangular figure, because if I change the width or height it change for both

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning}

\tikzset{
box/.style args = {#1/#2}{draw, minimum width=#1mm, minimum height=#2mm, 
                          inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
box/.default = 10/15,
       }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 9mm and 12mm,
                > = Latex]
\node (m1) [box=9/12] {};
\node (m2) [box=9/12,below] at (m1.south) {};
\node (m3) [box, above right=of m1.east] {};
\node (m4) [box, below right=of m2.east] {};
\draw[->]   (m1.center) to [bend  left] (m3.west);
\draw[->]   (m2.center) to [bend right] (m4.west);
\foreach \i [count=\j] in {north west, north east, south west, south east}
{
\node[above right, text=red] at (m1.\i) {\j};
\node[above right, text=red] at (m3.\i) {\j};
}
\foreach \i [count=\j] in {south west, south east, north west, north east}
{
\node[below right, text=blue] at (m2.\i) {\j};
\node[below right, text=blue] at (m4.\i) {\j};
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note*:

- command for drawing an arrow is `\draw[->] (<coordinate 1>) -- (<coordinate 2>);` or in your case `\draw[->]   (m1.center) to [bend  left] (m3.west);`
- arrow head is determined by `>`, its kinds are described in TikZ & PGF manual, chapter *16 Arrows*, page 191

Comment: please can you watch my code, is it possible to simplify?

Comment: @nette, see edited answer.

Comment: thanks a lot, it can be answer, but in my problem the the two rectangular is not the same dimension, and i can not find how to change that in your code

Comment: @nette, style for nodes enable define desired size. Set are default values 10mm (width) and 15mm (height), but you can change this as is done at first two nodes in code: `\node (m1) [box=9/12] {};` Just change `9/12` according to your wish, for example `22/33` which gives rectangle shape with 22mm width and 33mm height. BTW, my answer is complete and solve your problem, so it "is" answer and not only "can be".